# Married couple, high combined income: Can we contribute to IRA, on top of 401k?

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, contribution, limits

My wife and I earn between $180,000 and $210,000 combined. The amount varies due to job changes and side consulting. She puts about 4% of her salary into a 401k which is fully matched. I put in 6% and that's matched up to 4%.

I want to save more money. I plan on increasing my 401k contribution to $13,000 per year. But I also want to put away more pre-tax money, if I can, in an IRA. Is it possible to put extra money in IRA when our combined income is this high? What is the exact figure that I alone can put in an IRA?

Thanks.

Comment: Traditional IRA contributions are not _limited_ for high-income earners (or for those whose employers _offer_ retirement accounts to their employees, regardless of whether an employee participates or not) whereas Roth IRA contributions are not permitted at all beyond a certain level of income. What _is_ limited for Traditional IRA contributions is how much, if any, of the contribution can be deducted from current taxable income; high-earners don't get this break at all. For current levels of phase-out of this break look at the IRS website or Publication 590 for the numbers.

Comment: Nice answer, why not load it as such?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer There are too many nuances, and the topic has been thrashed to death over and over again on money.SE. Since I just didn't have enough time to write an answer and frame it all correctly, I opted for the comment.

Comment: Point noted. We probably have a duplicate post here, and this one should be closed. I'll look later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With these income levels you **cannot** *deduct* any IRA contribution. I.e.: you cannot save *pre-tax*, as you want.

But you still can *contribute* to IRA (as a *non-deductible contribution*), and using the "[loophole](http://littleadvisor.wordpress.com/2013/11/06/the-roth-ira-loophole-retirement-planning-for-high-earners/)" transfer the contribution to Roth (you are probably over the limit to be able to contribute to Roth directly).

For pre-tax contributions - max out your 401k.